# VC++ Project: unresolved external symbol HidD_GetHidGuid

Tags: visual-c++, arm, msdn, hid

I'm trying to build a project (for ARM) to facilitate the communication over an HID device. Here are the details of what I have:

- PC with Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2011 Developer Preview
- WDK

A microsoft library function FindKnownHidDevices() makes a call to HidD_GetHidGuid() in my project. However, Linker doesn't like this and complains:

*error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HidD_GetHidGuid referenced in function "unsigned char __cdecl FindKnownHidDevices*

I already have all of following workarounds in my project with no success so far:

- Include hid.lib & SetupAPI.lib in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencings under configuration manager of VS 2011
- Include hidsdi.h under "VC++ Directories -> Include Directories" in Configuration Manager of VS 2011
- Include hidsdi.h in the .h version of .c file which makes a call to the function HidD_GetHidGuid() using extern "C"

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

If the code compiles OK, then the compiler is finding the correct header files.  As the linker is failing, this suggests that it cannot find the specified .lib files.

Have you downloaded and installed the WoA SDK?  The required lib files may not actually be in the linker folder for ARM targets (they're not in the default installation for Studio 11 Developer Preview).